# Matlab: "for loop" doesn't decrement

Tags: matlab

Can someone please help me out with this loop over here? Matlab simple refuses to consider the `for o=k:k-20` statement inside the if statement.

```
if d(k)<=-1.5 || d(k) >=1.5
        k
        tab=tab+1
        6
        %table_results(k,:)=[5, d(k), E(k,1), b(k,1), F(k,1)];
        for o=k:k-20  
            5
            if abs(d(o))<abs(d(o-1))
            bench_value=o;
            break;
            end
        end
    .
    .
    .
    .
    end
```

Comment: Silly me,should have thought about the increment!. Thank you all; my faith in humanity has been restored. @thanks johnny, couldn't tick you answer as correct too (one answer :() .But thanks a lot. I think I can sleep peacefully now.

Comment: No problem , hope it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for o=k:-1:k-20
```

When you write `for variable=1:5` (for example) Matlab will expand `1:5` into `[1 2 3 4 5]` and pass each value to `for`. Since you're ranging from `k` to `k-20`, the `:` operator returns an empty array, because it increments the value from the first to the last value. In order to decrement it, you should pass `-1` in the middle. For example, `5:-1:1` will expand to `[5 4 3 2 1]`.

Comment: Some more information is available in the [docs of `colon (:)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

Answer (score 2):

The expression `for o=k:k-20` can be rewritten as a `while` loop as:

```
o = k;
while (o < k-20)
  % Do something
  o = o+1;
end
```

From here it should be a bit more clear, that you'll never enter the loop because when you start, `o` is already greater than `k-20`.

If you meant for `o` to go from `k` to `k-20` *backwards*, than you should write it as: `for o=k:-1:k-20`, where `-1` implies that it should *decrement* `o`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for o=k:k-20
```

This statement would give "o" a null vector because MATLAB assumes o=k:1:k-20 by default where :1: in the middle is the incremental jump , to decrement you have to add -1 instead of this 1 so MATLAB will know that you want to decrement in the for loop